# Can't build any MonoMac samples on MonoDevelop 3.0 in OS X

Tags: mono, monodevelop, monomac

I just did a clean install of MonoDevelop 3.0 in OS X (10.7.2) and then did a Git checkout of [MonoMac](https://github.com/mono/monomac).  I can't build any of the samples included in the MonoMac repository, and I get the same error every time after the output says the build succeeded:

```
Build failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Full sample build output:

```
Cleaning Solution: Fire (Debug)

Cleaning: Fire (Debug)
Removing output files...
Clean complete

Building Solution: Fire (Debug)

Building: Fire (Debug)
Performing main compilation...
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/bin/dmcs /noconfig "/out:/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.exe" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll" "/r:/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG"  /t:exe "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/MainWindow.cs" "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/MainWindowController.cs" "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/MainWindow.xib.designer.cs" "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/Main.cs" "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/AppDelegate.cs" "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/MainMenu.xib.designer.cs" 

Compiling interface definitions
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.app/Contents/Resources/MainWindow.nib" "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/MainWindow.xib"
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/MainWindow.xib:2: warning: Content rectangle not entirely on screen with the menu bar (May not be completely visible for all screen resolutions and configurations) [9]
/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.app/Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib" "/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/MainMenu.xib"

Copying content files
Copying '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.exe' to '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.app/Contents/MonoBundle/Fire.exe'
Copying '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.exe.mdb' to '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.app/Contents/MonoBundle/Fire.exe.mdb'
Copying '/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll' to '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MonoMac.dll'
Copying '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/fire.png' to '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.app/Contents/Resources/fire.png'
Copying '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/smoke.png' to '/Users/dave/Dropbox/Code/MonoMac/monomac/samples/Fire/bin/Debug/Fire.app/Contents/Resources/smoke.png'
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings

Updating application manifest

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build successful.
Build failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing this is a bug and we need to first roll back to the previous version and then forward this to BugZilla for inform them.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  I'm not positive how this kind of query is expected to be handled on SO, but for me it would be helpful if there was any of 1) A link to this as a bug in the database or 2) A link to an article where a monodevelop developer acknowledges the issue and suggests a workaround, or 3) steps to better diagnose what's happening, because the error listed, same as I get, is incredibly opaque and if I need to file a bug it would be great to include meaningful data for a repro, but I don't now how to do that with this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue. The problem is that MonoDevelop cannot find the MacOSX sdk's on your system (presumably you are using an Xcode version older than 4.3?).

I'm working on a fix for this for MonoDevelop 3.0.2

Comment: Yeah, I've got XCode 4.2 right now.  MonoDevelop 2.9.5 works fine for now.

Comment: I think I've fixed it now: http://files.xamarin.com/~jeff/MonoDevelop-3.0.1js1.dmg - could you verify that it works?

Comment: I get a build error saying "SDK build settings not found for Mac OS X 10.0" on file "info.plist"

Comment: ugh, ok... I'll keep digging I guess. At least the NRE is gone.

Comment: can you try http://files.xamarin.com/~jeff/MonoDevelop-3.0.1js2.dmg and see if that fixes it? I had inverted an if-statement by accident.

Comment: Looking good! The samples are building and running now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the fact that I had a conflict in a Info.plist file that the IDE couldn't identify was bad. Just had to resolve the conflict and rebuild.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. Just hit the same issue, for some reason MonoDevelop cleared out `Info.plist`.